# If a Point Admits an Integral Curve on an Interval then a Neighborhood Does too On the Same Interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
Let $V:U\to \R^n$ be a (continuous) vector field on an open set $U$ of $\R^n$. Suppose we have a point $\mathbf p\in U$ and an open interval $I\subseteq \R$ such that there is an integral curve $\gamma^{\mathbf p}:I\to U$ starting at $0$ (This means that $I$ contains $0$ and $\gamma^{\mathbf p}(0)=\mathbf p$). Let $t_0\in I$.

> Does there exist a neighborhood $N$ of $\mathbf p$ and an open interval $J$ containing $0$ and $t_0$ such that for all points $\mathbf q$ of $N$, there is an integral curve $\gamma^{\mathbf q}:J\to U$ starting at $\mathbf q$?

I am aware of the following theorem of which the above is, if true, a stronger version:

Let $V:U\to \R^n$ be a vector field on an open subset $U$ of $\R^n$ and $\mathbf p$ be any point in $U$. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a neighborhood $N$ of $\mathbf p$ such that for each point $\mathbf q\in N$, there is an integral curve $\gamma^{\mathbf q}:(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\to U$.

Does anybody know if the thing in the block quote is true? If so can somebody provide a proof or point me towards a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the [Cauchy-Peano existence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem) takes care of existence of integral curves for any continuous vector field.

Comment: The theorem given in the link talks about functions mapping $\mathbf R^2$ into $\mathbf R$ and then considers a differential equation formed from that whose local existence of solutions is claimed. It looks different from what I am asking above.

Comment: It talks about $\Bbb R^2$, but I think that's an oversight, the french version of the page talks about continuous vector fields on $\Bbb R^n$ for arbitrary $n$.